# How to load xml file in scala with databinding enabled

Tags: xml, scala

Suppose I have xml file with contents like this:

```
<example name={name}/>
```

Is it possible to load this file from Scala and have {name} replaced with the value of the name in scope?

So something like XML.loadFile, but that does databinding in the same way as Scala's XML literal.

Note that more complex examples should work as well, e.g.

```
<example name={name}>
   {for (hobby <- hobbies) yield <hobby>{hobby}</hobby>}
</example>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object XmlBinder {

  // "twitter" at "http://maven.twttr.com"
  // "com.twitter" %% "util-eval" % "3.0.0"
  import com.twitter.util.Eval
  import scala.xml.Elem

  private val template =
    """|<example name={name}>
       |  {for (hobby <- hobbies) yield <hobby>{hobby}</hobby>}
       |</example>""".stripMargin

  val name = "name"
  val hobbies = List("hobby 1", "hobby 2")

  def bind(): Elem = new Eval()("import XmlBinder._\n" + template)
}
```

Comment: yes, that's what I feared the answer would be. So, short of evaluating the scala source code, there is no support for this, right?

Answer (score 3):

Would this be sufficient?

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.util.matching.Regex.Groups
import scala.xml.XML

type Data = mutable.Map[Symbol, Any]

object Data {
  def empty = mutable.Map.empty[Symbol, Any]
}

class Assignment(identifier: Symbol, data: Data) {
  def :=(value: Any) {
    data(identifier) = value
  }
}

implicit def symbol2assignment(id: Symbol)(implicit data: Data) =
  new Assignment(id, data)

def bind(template: String)(implicit data: Data) = {
  val attributes = """=\{([^{}]+)}""".r
    .replaceAllIn((_: String), _ match {
      case Groups(identifier) =>
        "=\"%s\"".format(data(Symbol(identifier)))
    })
  val rest = """\{([^{}]+)}""".r
    .replaceAllIn((_: String), _ match {
      case Groups(identifier) =>
        data(Symbol(identifier)).toString
    })
  (attributes andThen rest andThen XML.loadString)(template)
}

implicit val data = Data.empty

'name := "bob"
'text := "hi there"

val bound = bind("<ex name={name}>{text}</ex>")
assert(bound == <ex name="bob">hi there</ex>)
```